# Classification report while scoring on a multi-class production dataset

Tags: arrays, reshape, text-classification, multiclass-classification

I built a multiclass model with top 5 classes using FRCB Consumer complaints dataset. Following is the distribution of train and test samples.

[Volume Distr of Train and Test samples](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qFUjw.png)

After hyper parameter tuning and model fitting, I got train and test wtd f1-score as 91% and 74% respectively.

Then, I score this model on an unseen data having only top 3 of the 5 classes. Because we want to see how a multiclass model performs in a production environment having more or less classes than it was trained on.

I followed following steps:

Step 1: Convert scoring dataset of 3 classes into one-hot encoded dummy variables.

```
%%time

# prepare text data for LSTM
#max_features = 20_000
#MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH = 250
tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=max_features, split=' ')

#hange these to dfA, dfB and dfC depening upon model you want to fit and score on remaining two.
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(df2["cleaned_text"]) 
X2 = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(df2["cleaned_text"])
X2 = pad_sequences(X2, maxlen = MAX_SEQUENCE_LENGTH)
y2 = pd.get_dummies(df2['category_id'], dtype=int).values
```

Step 2: Pad 2 columns with zeros to equal the number of classes

```
# create a new array of zeros with shape ( , 5-n)
zeros = np.zeros((y2.shape[0], 5 - y2.shape[1]))
# concatenate the original array and the new array of zeros
y_2f = np.hstack((y2, zeros))
```

This is the shape of my ground truth dataset before and after appending 2 columns with zeros.

```
print(y2.shape)  # original array shape before appending 0 columns
print(y_2f.shape)  # final array shape after appending 0 columns, prints: ( , 5)
```

> (4833, 3)
> (4833, 5)

Step 3: Use the fitted model to score on production dataset having only top 3 classes.

```
#Using the current model, score on df2
#scoring
predictions_test2 = model.predict(X2)

#finding position (cateogory_id) of class with maximum probability
classes_test2 = np.argmax(predictions_test2, axis = 1)

#finding probability of class with maximum probability
probability_test2 = np.max(predictions_test2, axis=1)  # this will give the probability of the predicted class in test sample
```

Step 4: Convert predicted classe to numpy arrays

```
# convert to numpy arrays
classes_test2_pred = np.array(classes_test2)
```

These are shapes of arrays

```
print(classes_test2_pred)
print(y_test2_gt)

print(classes_test2_pred.shape)
print(np.unique(classes_test2_pred))
print(y_test2_gt.shape)
print(np.unique(y_test2_gt))
print(np.unique(y_2f))
```

> [1 1 3 ... 0 0 0]
> [0 0 0 ... 2 2 2]
> (4833,)
> [0 1 2 3 4]
> (4833,)
> [0 1 2]
> [0. 1.]

Step 4: in ground truth where 0 was padded in step 2, find index value of every observation as it will be the true category_id of that complaint text

y_test2_gt = np.argmax(y_2f, axis = 1)

checking the shapes and values in ground truths and predicted dataset

```
print(y_test2_gt)
print(y_test2_gt.shape)

print(classes_test2_pred)
print(classes_test2_pred.shape)

print(np.unique(y_test2_gt))
print(np.unique(classes_test2_pred))
```

> [0 0 0 ... 2 2 2]
> (4833,)
> [1 0 0 ... 1 1 1]
> (4833,)
> [0 1 2]
> [0 1 2 3 4]

Step 5: Print classification report

#print classification report of dataset2 scoring using modelC
print(classification_report(y_test2_gt, classes_test2_pred, digits=5))

At this step, I get following f1-score and wtd f1-score

```
        precision    recall  f1-score   support

       0    0.70708   0.30790   0.42900      3277
       1    0.24132   0.58511   0.34171      1034
       2    0.00000   0.00000   0.00000       522
       3    0.00000   0.00000   0.00000         0
       4    0.00000   0.00000   0.00000         0

accuracy                        0.33395      4833
```

macro avg    0.18968   0.17860   0.15414      4833
weighted avg    0.53106   0.33395   0.36399      4833

I am sure this is not right because, classes 0, 1 and 2 were used for model fitting using exactly same records of 3277, 1034 and 522 respectively so f1-score cannot be different to the classification report shown before step 1.

I expect f1-score of 0,1 and 2 classes to be 86, 95 and 85% respectively

I am unable to figure out what I am doing wrong so it will be of great help if someone can assist in my logic.

Happy to share more information if required

I tried changing shapes of dataset scored using model and ground truth dataset.

I expect f1-scoreof top 3 classes to be exactly same as in train and test sample (i.e. wtd avg of f1-score in train sample and test sample for all 3 classes)